# How to read timestamp and how to subtract two timestamps?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have the following code to get (timestamp) and (NOW timestamp).
I subtract them to get the difference between them but I get a number like 123456 and I can not understand how much this number represent.
I want to check if the difference between those two dates are less than one hour, how?

```
final_time = new Date(2013, 11, 11, 11, 11);
c_date = new Date();
offset_time = c_date.getTimezoneOffset();
var n1 = Math.abs(offset_time);
current_date = new Date(c_date.getTime() - n1 * 60 * 1000);

alert(current_date-final_time);
```

Comment: running your code gives ...2598440754 milis is 721 hours. (if swapping over the subtration at the end to give a positive number, c_date.getTime() - final_time.getTime()).  Just take that and work out if that is greater than '60 * 60 * 1000'.  Just see 'codebox's answer below, its more eloquent than my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the difference between the two dates in milliseconds if you do:

```
var diffInMillis = c_date.getTime() - final_time.getTime()
```

To find out if this is less than 1 hour you can do this:

```
var isLessThan1Hour = diffInMillis < 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: but does it affect dates? i mean if i want to subtruct two dates ?
this code work for today dates with different hour times but does it work for two different dates??

Comment: yes, the getTime() method is confusingly named - its gets the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date and time

Comment: can u please tell me what the 1000 represent??

Comment: 1000 converts seconds into milliseconds. 60 * 60 * 1000 gives you the number of milliseconds in 1 hour

Comment: sorry but each time I alert the isLessThan1Hour it gave me a false, even i set a date with one minute difference can u check this please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly subtracting the timestamps try to diff the dates from which you can individually get hours.From then on one can do a simple maths to do the difference.

That's a more clear and maintainable approach